# Abstract method that implements tooltip

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I need to create a method that would display help information in windows forms when the user hover over a certain controller, I got all that figured out but the issue is how can I apply it to other existing forms without have to duplicate the code?

The forms are a mix between c# and vb.

Comment: yeah you can make a base form, however this seems messy, or you could create a helper method and hook up the same events and just call it. however without seeing the code or knowing what jar of magical wonderment you have going on its hard to give you any advice

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: I created a base form and implemented the mouse hover method there, then inherited that method into another form and it works fine, the problem that I face now is form1, which is the form that I need to inherit the hover method from the base form is written in vb and already have a base form also written in vb which forces me to put the implementation of the mouse hover in the vb base form the code for the hover method is below:

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1; private void PrepareTooltips() { ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(); foreach(Control ctrl in this.Controls) { if (ctrl is Button && ctrl.Tag is string) { ctrl.MouseHover += new EventHandler(delegate(Object o, EventArgs a) { var btn = (Control)o; ToolTip1.SetToolTip(btn, btn.Tag.ToString()); }); } } }

Comment: the portion that dose not translate directly to vb is: ctrl.MouseHover += new EventHandler(delegate(Object o, EventArgs a) { var btn = (Control)o; ToolTip1.SetToolTip(btn, btn.Tag.ToString());